# How to ignore "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute" Lint warning

Tags: android, build.gradle, lint

Several 3rd party .jar libraries I use are throwing thousands of Lint warnings like this one:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.inneractive.api.ads.sdk.IAmraidWebView$a) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

How can I suppress these warnings using `lintOptions` in my build.gradle?

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    disable 'WHAT_IS_THE_NAME_OF_THE_RULE_TO_DISABLE_HERE?'
  }
}
```